# RTLinux on X86 PC

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, operating-system

**Preface:**
Linux and RT is a new realm of discovery, as I am mostly familiar with the Windows environment & Visual Studio C++ development.

**Goal:**
Execute a few sample 'C' programs on RTLinux, for analysis of deadlines and timing.

**Method:**
I do not currently have a "target" hardware device. However, I do have a PC with an Intel Core i5.

**Questions:**

- Can I install in a dual boot configuration to **preserve my every day
  Windows 7 configuration?** Will it work with Ubuntu? This is my biggest concern unless I purchase another PC.
- Can RTLinux install and execute correctly? I do [see it supports x86](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Which_architectures_does_the_CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_patch_support.3F)
  but has this been done successfully on a PC configuration - and does it have a GUI to work with?
- Are there are **reliable simulators** that can run on Windows, bypassing installing the OS, that will give good benchmarks of
  timing, say of a context switch?
- Any other options to run sample programs on RTLinux that I may not be
  aware of ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but running a real time OS in a simulator on a non-RT OS to benchmark its performance characteristics seems a little absurd to me.

Comment: @us2012: ok thanks, I am not familiar with this realm or how accurate those simulations are.

Comment: @us2012 - it might work if the benchmarks were against some kind of emulated CPU cycle counter, but I don't know off the top of my head what level of detail/fidelity is available there.  For smaller embedded systems that sometimes have literal cycle-accurate emulators (a very different beast from a typical modern virtual machine), such data can in fact be collected, though not of course in real-world time.

Comment: @chris-stratton: Any idea on the Ubuntu and RTLinux on a Windows machine? Have you done this combo? from what I can tell, in theory, I should be able to download Ubuntu, dual boot to Linux, then patch the kernel with the Vanilla kernel, then find the corresponding hard real time patch.....?

Comment: I'd expect it would work, what I don't know is if you could get useful performance data against counters in the vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu on a PC with Windows 7 but you will need a separate disk partition and things can go wrong. I have different versions of Ubuntu and other Linux 32 bit and 64 bit distros installed on USB sticks, USB disks and an eSATA disk. The USB devices, at least for Ubuntu, all boot successfully on my desktops and laptops. Booting time and details of my Linux programs are in the following. All are compiled and run from command lines, where commands are provided with the source codes that are free to download.

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/linux%20benchmarks.htm

The distros are copied to bootable USB sticks or CDs/DVDs. At least older releases of Ubuntu were easily installed on USB devices or on an hard disk partition but bootable from USB. For later ones, I installed the distros on a laptop, with the disk drive disconnected. Then you can’t go wrong.

I believe that RTLinux uses the same GCC compiler as other Linuxes.